# Multiple expressions for an NSPredicate?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, nspredicate

So I'm trying to do more than just one left expression, and one right expression.  Is this possible with an NSPredicate?

Here is the "custom" solution I'm using now, but I don't think it's ideal:
[image: Conditions]

Is it possible to re use this?

Note: the Health dropdown has about 9 options, I'd rather not have like 9*4 permutations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comparison predicate only supports a single left expression.  It does not make sense to have more than one.

However, this left expression doesn't have to be a single property name; it could be a keypath, like this:

```
friend.health < 30
```